# How do I make a function stop when an error occurs?

Tags: vimscript

I just wrote a function which tries to call another function, but I got the syntax wrong. However, I was horrified to see that the next line in my  function happily started executing anyway. It is as if every line of my vimscript function has a try-catch around it; oh no! How do I disable this?

For example, try running `:call AmendCommit("098ajwe")<CR>`. After the failure of the call to FixupCommit, the next line still tries to execute!

```
fu! FixupCommit(commit_hash)
  execute "Git commit --fixup=" . a:commit_hash
endfunction

fu! AmendCommit(commit_hash)
  FixupCommit(commit_hash)
  execute "Git rebase --autosquash " . a:commit_hash . "~1"
endfunction
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See `:h :func-abort`, like

```
function! AmendCommit(commit_hash) abort
    ...
```

This is recommended practice in the current version of VimScript.

In Vim9Script "abort" is planned to be the default behaviour, and so the word "abort" won't be needed/supported.